# Column not exist in order by clause

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize to query in to a table like this:

```
  const students = await User.findAll({
attributes: ['id', [Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName"`), 'name']],
where: {
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      firstName: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`
      }
    },
    {
      lastName: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`
      }
    },
    Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" ILIKE '%${search}%'`)
  ]
},
order: Sequelize.literal(`"organization_users"."firstName" ${NATURAL_SORT} ${sort}`),
limit,
offset: limit * (page - 1),
distinct: true
});
```

And it work ok but if I include some model, the column "firstName" is not exist:

```
  const students = await User.findAll({
attributes: ['id', [Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName"`), 'name']],
where: {
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      firstName: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`
      }
    },
    {
      lastName: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`
      }
    },
    Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" ILIKE '%${search}%'`)
  ]
},
include: [
  { model: ProgressGrade, as: 'student_progress_grade', required: true, where: { courseId } },
  {
    model: CourseRole,
    as: 'course_roles',
    attributes: [],
    where: { roleName: 'Student' },
    required: true
  },
  { model: Course, as: 'courses', attributes: [], where: { id: courseId }, required: true }
],
order: Sequelize.literal(`"organization_users"."firstName" ${NATURAL_SORT} ${sort}`),
limit,
offset: limit * (page - 1),
distinct: true
});
```

Error message:

> error: SequelizeDatabaseError: column organization_users.firstName
>   does not exist

This is the first time I run into this problem, I did many search but hopeless. Anyone have an idea about how Sequelize work here?

I'm using Sequelize 5.21.5 running on Nodejs 13.8.0, PostgreSQL 10.12

Comment: Please share the exact error here

Answer (score 1):

Please set `subQuery` property to false as follows -

```
 const students = await User.findAll({
attributes: ['id', [Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName"`), 'name']],
where: {
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      firstName: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`
      }
    },
    {
      lastName: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`
      }
    },
    Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" ILIKE '%${search}%'`)
  ]
},
include: [
  { model: ProgressGrade, as: 'student_progress_grade', required: true, where: { courseId } },
  {
    model: CourseRole,
    as: 'course_roles',
    attributes: [],
    where: { roleName: 'Student' },
    required: true
  },
  { model: Course, as: 'courses', attributes: [], where: { id: courseId }, required: true }
],
order: Sequelize.literal(`"organization_users"."firstName" ${NATURAL_SORT} ${sort}`),
limit,
offset: limit * (page - 1),
distinct: true,
subQuery: false
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please post the previous query generated by Sequelize and its output and query generated after modification and respective output? It will help to understand the problem

Comment: I found out a work around by add "firstName" to the attributes list

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM, Glad to know that!